# Write a stream into a file with NIO and the Channel system

Tags: java, nio

I have an inputStream and i want to write it to a file.

I saw NIO and the FileChannel which has the method "transferTo" ou "transferFrom" and i know how to create the WriteableChannel, but i don't know to transform my inputStream to a ReadableChannel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [`Channels.newChannel(java.io.InputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newChannel(java.io.InputStream)) method.

> #### newChannel
>
> ```
>   public static ReadableByteChannel newChannel(InputStream in)
> ```
>
> Constructs a channel that reads bytes from the given stream.
>
> The resulting channel will not be buffered; it will simply redirect
>    its I/O operations to the given stream.  Closing the channel will in
>    turn cause the stream to be closed.
>
> **Parameters:**`in` - The stream from which bytes are to be read
>   **Returns:**A new readable byte channel

Comment: ChannelS (you should edit your link text). And that's exactly what i was looking for. Thanks !