# Create Zip archive from Filechannels

Tags: java, nio

I am trying to add a file to a zip archive. I want to do something like this

```
public void zipFile(Path fileToZip, Path zipFile) {
    ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(zipFile, CREATE, APPEND));
    FileChannel outputChannel = new FileOutputStream(zipOut).getChannel() //How to go from zipoutputstream to FileChannel...
    FileChannel inputChannel = FileChannel.open(zipFile, READ)
    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileToZip.toString());
    zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

    inputChannel.transferTo (0, inputChannel.size(), outputChannel);

    outputChannel.close();
    inputChannel.close();
}
```

but ZipOutputStream doesn't have a getChannel() like FileOutputStream does. How can I create a zip file using channels?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write a stream into a file with NIO and the Channel system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873643/write-a-stream-into-a-file-with-nio-and-the-channel-system)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn any OutputStream into a Channel using the [`Channels.newChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newChannel(java.io.OutputStream)) method.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this is very very easy to do. Don't use channels or anything. Just create a zipfilesystem and copy the files over.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html